# Better method to append to output crontabs

Tags: sh, cron

So i have simple shell commands to ping websites to retrieve data about said websites.

For example one of my pinging.sh looks like this:

```
ping -R -c 120 blar.org.cn >> pingdata.txt
ping -R -c 120 another.net >> pingdata.txt
```

But then my crontabs look like this:

```
7 * * * ./pinging.sh >> pingdata.log
```

The pingdata.log doesn't output. Is it best to do it through the crontab or through the script? I assumed the crontab would be better because it would cover the entire script rather than having to write it out multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate the full path of your script in the cronjob, together with the binary running it.

For example:

```
7 * * * * /bin/sh /home/you/pinging.sh >> /home/you/pingdata.log
```

Note also you are just adding 4 parameters to the cronjob, whereas you need at least 5:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

You can test your cron syntax with [Crontab guru](http://crontab.guru/) (---> http://crontab.guru/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the full path has to be from which position? I know that it executes the .sh because it outputs to pingdata.txt so It must be something to do with the /home/you/pingdata.log. I just assumed that the crontabs were in the same directory I made the scripts?

Comment: @Hidden no, the cronjobs run in a very tiny environment in which you cannot assume much. That's why you need to make full paths explicit.

Comment: Okay I shall do that, thank you. Why does executing the .sh work? if I haven't provided the entire path?

Comment: Also how do i determine the starting position for the path? cd ~ ?

Comment: @Hidden honestly, I don't know why it ran. I just did a test and -to me- it runs the cronjob, but it cannot find the script, so nothing happens. To know the full path of your script say `readlink -e <your_script>`.

Comment: Thank you, also is /bin/sh necessary if it is at the top of my script as #!bin/sh

Comment: @Hidden no. If you already have that header, you can just say `<path>/script.sh`, because the interpreter will learn what binary to use when seeing that header.

Answer (score 0):

First, the executable must be provided as full path in cron.
Example:

```
7 * * * *  /bin/bash /path/to/pinging.sh
```

Second, create a wrapper script for **pinging.sh >> pingdata.log** and add that to crontab.

Third, your crontab entry is wrong. There must be 5 fields whereas your's have 4 (maybe that's a typo ?)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I notice you have /bin/bash in the path. In my pinging.sh file I have #!bin/sh at the top

Comment: And do you know any references to these wrapper scripts you speak of?

Comment: I meant putting the command in another script to reduce the space related issues.